# Solution of PDE $(D^2-D')(D-2D')z=e^{2x+y}+ xy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am facing difficulty in finding the solution of the following PDE:
$(D^2-D')(D-2D')z=e^{2x+y}+ xy$
The factors of the auxiliary equation are not linear. How do we find complementary function and particular integral in such cases? Please suggest.

**Note** - $D=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $D^{'}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Comment: I don't see a PDE in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @JJacquelin Here $D$ is the partial derivative of $z$ w.r.t.$x$ and $D'$ is the partial derivative of $z$ w.r.t.$y$.

Comment: Why not use standard notation like $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$? Disrespecting your readers is not a great way of eliciting good answers.